# Android Background Network service

Tags: android, service, xmpp

I am developing an XMPP chat client.I am using Background service to connect to network XMPP server.however when i start the server it gives Network on UI thread Exception.
when i downgrade the Android SDK to 8 it gives ANR exception

I tried starting the Service from onCreate method of the SPlash screen.

```
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent serviceIntent=new Intent();
                serviceIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SeetiService.class);
                startService(serviceIntent);


            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        Thread serviceThread=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Intent serviceIntent=new Intent();
                serviceIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SeetiService.class);
                startService(serviceIntent);

            }
        };
        serviceThread.start();
```

But i still get the Same network on Main UI thread.

Can some one help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to start two Service simultaneously.AFAIK You can not start it with above piece of code.But i will show why you are facing ANR.

```
Intent serviceIntent=new Intent();
serviceIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SeetiService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

The above code is supposed to run on UI thread.and if you want to run it from another thread you must embedd it into runOnUiThread.So your block should look like.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{@Override
  public void run()
  {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SeetiService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
      }
    });

  }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```